# Long Negation Bar in LaTeX

Tags: latex

how can I produce long negation lines in latex.
It should look like on the left of the following equations
[image]

I used `\[ \bar{(A \land B)} \]` but that just added a bar over the `\land`

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I believe you want `\overline`.

```
\[ \overline{(A \land B)} \]
```

Comment: Be careful with `overline`. It will smush  together adjacent overlines: $\overline{Z}\overline{V}$